# when i click on button to showing next activity it shows only white screen

Tags: android

When i click on button it shows onlywhite screen not the view of next activity. I can't find why it happen pls give me solution......
my whole code is here

ActivityMain.java

```
package com.rahul.intentswitchingwithdata;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
   public void go(View v){
         Intent i= new Intent(this,Next.class);
         startActivity(i);}
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/activity_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.rahul.intentswitchingwithdata.MainActivity">

      <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hello World!" />
      <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:onClick="go"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next.java

```
public class Next extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle 
    persistentState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
   }
}
```

next.xml

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="#123"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.rahul.intentswitchingwithdata">
   <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:supportsRtl="true"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Next"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have "overridden" the wrong `onCreate` method:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle 
    persistentState)
```

you should use this instead:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){...code}
```

`onCreate(Bundle)` is used for initialization mean where your all UI initialization like view are done ,[docs link for depth details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

`onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` as it, itself suggesting , it is used for persistent mean reuse the old intent (supplied first time to this activity) while recreating it , you can enable reusing by adding a `persistableMode` flag to your activity so that activity will be persisted across reboots . try this doc link for [other options details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode) .

**Note :** You can only use `onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)` in API level 21(Android Lollipop 5.0) or above.