# What is the usage of onCreate method second implementation in Android Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have alway used `onCreate` method inside my `Activity` lifecycle to start or restore from a saved state, but recently found that there is another onCreate method which contains a `PersistableBundle`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

}
```

I only found that it has been added since Android 21.

Could anyone please give a complete information about this method, when it calls and the usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when i click on button to showing next activity it shows only white screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327208/when-i-click-on-button-to-showing-next-activity-it-shows-only-white-screen)  you can try the answer here

Comment: I have studied this document but unfortunately I didn't get the point: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode

Comment: The point is that you can save the activity state between device restarts by putting stuff in a special bundle.

Comment: Then why we need another method implemented? Why android doesn't use the saved state even after rebooting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I've been able to gather, if you set a property on your activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:persistableMode="persistAcrossReboots"
</activity>
```

then you can use the `PersistableBundle` to recover data after a system shutdown and restart. In other words, a normal Bundle object will keep a record of your `savedInstanceState` as long as the application is alive. You can use the `PersistableBundle` to save data in the event the system is shutdown.

You can also use `persistNever` or `persistRootOnly` instead of `persistAcrossReboots`.

You can find more info on the docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode