# Nothing is getting displayed while using one BaseActivity in whole project

Tags: android, android-activity

I have made one BaseActivity for all activity to set up headers and other stuff for all but nothing is getting displayed when I am launching the app.

Here's the code for **BaseActivity**:

```
    abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
            setContentView(getContentView())
            onViewReady(savedInstanceState, intent)
        }

        abstract fun getContentView(): Int
        abstract fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, intent: Intent?)
    }
```

and here's the **MainActivity**:

```
    class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {


        override fun getContentView(): Int = R.layout.activity_main

        override fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, intent: Intent?) {

        }
    }
```

Manifest file:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.unigem">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".gem.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `BaseActivity` you are overriding wrong `onCreate()`, that is `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)`.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
        setContentView(getContentView())
        onViewReady(savedInstanceState, intent)
    }
```

Instead of the above version of `onCreate()` you need to override `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` like below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    setContentView(getContentView())
    onViewReady(savedInstanceState, intent)
}
```

Read more at [What is the usage of onCreate method second implementation in Android Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424394/what-is-the-usage-of-oncreate-method-second-implementation-in-android-activities) if you are curious about second implementation of `onCreate()` (the method which you overrided)