# savedInstanceState returning null

Tags: android

Can someone please explain why the value in my savedInstanceState is null?
I have 3 widgets, an EditText, Button and TextView. The person types in what they want. The Phrase pops up in the TextView. I want to keep the input when I flip the phone. I tried saving the state but when the Activity is recreated, my Toast says that it's null:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText input;
private TextView output;
private Button button;
private String newString = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "SAVED IS " + savedInstanceState.getString("example"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newString = input.getText().toString();
            output.setText(newString);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putString("example",newString);
}}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `activity recreated` , how and when it's getting recreated

Comment: When the device is rotated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this function `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`, the one  without `PersistableBundle outPersistentState`

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putString("example",newString);
}
```

[**void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, 
                PersistableBundle outPersistentState)**](http://void%20onSaveInstanceState%20(Bundle%20outState,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PersistableBundle%20outPersistentState)) this will only get called when you have attribute `persistableMode` specified in the activity tag inside manifest

You can read more [about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327208/when-i-click-on-button-to-showing-next-activity-it-shows-only-white-screen/40327237#40327237)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `String` variable that is global to your activity and define it upon restoringInstanceState.
Looks a little something like this:

```
String userInput;
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    userInput = savedInstanceState.getString("example") // Refers to your "outState.putString "example" <-- key
    output.setText(newString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code it works for me.

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("example",newString);
    }
```