# android: Activity won't start

Tags: android, android-activity

So, I have a menu with a few pictures and an `onClick` method which opens a new page. That works for all menu items except one. That one is written in exactly the same way as the rest, but when the menu item is clicked, a blank new page appears, with correct title, but - apparently - without calling `onCreate` method of the new activity.

There are no error messages either.

The code, where the Activitys are started:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = null;
    Context context = v.getContext();

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(context, BooksActivity.class);                     
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(context, GamesActivity.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(context, MusicActivity.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(context, FilesActivity.class);
            break;
        case 4:
            intent = new Intent(context, VideosActivity.class);
            break;
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);            
}
```

Works like a charm for every activity but FilesActivity. In the FilesActivity.onCreate method, I print a log:

```
Log.d(TAG, "initialized");
```

but that log is never shown.

Any idea what is going on here?

*Edit:*
All activities are added to the manifest in the same way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MusicActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_music"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.wilzek.hoerstift.MainActivity" />
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".FilesActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_files"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.wilzek.hoerstift.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

*Edit:* Files.Activity onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_files);
    Log.e(TAG, "INITIALIZED");

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.files_list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    try {
        files = Arrays.asList(USBCommunicationManager.getRootDir().listFiles());
        Log.e(TAG, "Root Dateien: " + files.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Root Dateien konnten nicht gefetcht werden. Yay denglish.");
    }

    filesAdapter = new FilesAdapter(this, files);
    listView.setAdapter(filesAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Have you added your activities to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Please show the manifest and that Activity code

Comment: Add your FilesActivity onCreate here

Comment: @cricket_007 here you go

Comment: @KapilG here the onCreate

Comment: If you don't see your debug log, it is possible that `setContentView()` is crashing because your layout file doesn;t exist or is badly configured. TYou should see some error/crash when that happens. To check, try to call `setContentView()` with a known good layout resource (like one from one of your working activities).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when i click on button to showing next activity it shows only white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327208/when-i-click-on-button-to-showing-next-activity-it-shows-only-white-screen) , remove `, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState` and read explanation in the given link

Comment: I think your issue with position ..app doesnt hit that intent .. add log there or try to debug it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In FilesActivity override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

instead of

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,  @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState);
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that was it.
An explanation of these two parameter would be higly appreciated, too.

Comment: I have never used it but here is the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)